# Normalize each row separately

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I would like to apply the normalization function of (first value - the value)/(standard deviation of each row) to each row separately.

For example:

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 30 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 40 | 5 | 8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1000 | 300 | 23 | 21 |

so I expect the first value of column "A" in each row will be zero.
imagine the rows are more than 1K.

I tried to use this code but does not work

```
for i in range(len(df)):
new_norm = df((df.iloc[i][0] - df.iloc[i,:])/df.std(axis=1))
df= df.apply(new_norm, axis=1)
df
```

I used this one also and the same error

```
df = df((df.iloc[:,0] - df.iloc[:,:]) / df.std(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1,2,3,10],    
    "A": [20,30,40,300],
    "B": [3,4,5,23],
    "C": [6,7,8,21]
})
vals = df.drop(columns=["ID"]).values
pd.DataFrame((vals[0, :] - vals) / vals.std(axis=0), columns=df.columns[1:])
```

output:

```
    A           B           C 
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1   -0.085377   -0.121101   -0.163846
2   -0.170755   -0.242202   -0.327693
3   -2.390566   -2.422019   -2.457696
```

Comment: I edited the question, the first value of cloumn A in each row should be zero, the function should be apply to each row separately. I used the "for i " cycle because I have about 10K rows in my dataframe so I can not vectorise it.

Comment: @SHAH "I have about 10K rows in my dataframe so I can not vectorise it." I couldn't find why? vectorize is very well for huge datasets and it's recommended. and please add your desired output for your sample data as a table